# Simple hello world runs but printf does not print to command line

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is my simple hello world program given to me by my professor. I was given this to copy as my first program in C. I am using visual studio 2013 as instructed and I am on a Surface Book running windows 10. A classmate that is on the exact same setup runs this program just fine. Mine will build and when I run without debugging the console window opens and no text prints. I cannot find a solution online.

Comment: Well, it looks correct. Maybe try "fflush(stdout);" after the printf-statement.
This will make sure that the stdout-buffer will be flushed.

Comment: some antivirus is known to interfere (I think Avast if I remember correctly). Try to disable the antivirus

Comment: @bolov do you know why and at which point? (just curious)

Comment: Buffer should be flushed as app closes, so no need for fflush(). Can you provide links to AV interfering with printf? I've never heard of it.

Comment: Just as test, try adding `while(1);` before `return`. (Note - you will have to force-close it...)

Comment: The code is perfectly fine. (You can also try it in some online compiler.) The problem must be with your setup or the way you try to execute the program.

Comment: Sometimes Visual Studio can close the window before you have time to see the printout. Try a `getchar();` before `return`.

Comment: I doubt a while(1) will help (unless the console flashes open then closes). If you do add a while(1), then you DO need an fflush before it. My guess is OP is looking in the wrong place for the results.

Comment: @John3136 Isn't it flushing at a newline?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Yes, standard output is line buffered by default, so no `fflush` should be needed in this program.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Possibly, but I wouldn't guarantee it (the specs may though, I'm just "some guy on the internet" ;-) If we are adding debug code, why not add a bit extra to avoid all risk?

Comment: @John3136 Well, some guy with 15k rep is not just a some guy :)

Comment: Does the window close immediately, or does it stick around?  Vanishing windows is a problem with some IDEs — and are one of the reasons I don't usually work in an IDE.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Don't let rep fool you! I can be just as wrong as the next guy. Especially when it comes to what is in language specs. A lot of what I know probably dates back to before things were in specs ;-)

Comment: There is absolutely *nothing* wrong with your code. As long as you have set the file as part of a project in VS2013, it should build and run fine. If it isn't, that is pointing to a problem with the VS2013 setup on Win10. I would search "*Windows 10 VS2013 no console output*" and see what turns up.

Comment: Minor: Change `int main()` to `int main(void)`. `int main()` is not standard..  Though I doubt this will solve the issue.

Comment: All I can say is, there's a reason Kernighan and Ritchie present this as Exercise 1, and why they offer that after you've solved it (which may indeed be arbitrarily difficult!), everything else is comparatively easy.

Comment: I would suggest putting a breakpoint in Visual Studio at the line "return 0"; Then debug the program.  That way the window will stay up and you would see the output if it's there.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your program doesn't just finish and close the console so quickly that you cannot see anything. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    fflush (stdout); /* Make sure string is outputted to std output */
    getchar(); /* waits for a key to finish */
    return 0;
}
```